# Local host issue apache

Tags: php, apache, localhost

I have been trying to get my local host to work. But I still haven't been able to solve it. I did everything I could. I change the listening port and restarted apache. I failed. I was given following error message. I would really appreciate if anyone can help me.

AH00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for yeshichoedons-MacBook-Pro.local
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Answer (score 0):

Try editing */etc/apache2/httpd.conf* and insert the following line:

`ServerName localhost`

Comment: where Do I insert it?

Comment: you can add it in the beginning of your file, outside of any <tags>. Some people also use ```ServerName localhost:80```. And don't forget to restart Apache with ```sudo service apache2 restart```